# return in catch block fails to be executed

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, web-applications

Basic example that throws an error because `tl` was not specified:

```javascript
function allmatches() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('data').getRange('A1').setValue(tl)
}
```

And to know if there were any errors in the execution in the Web App, I added a `try catch`:

```javascript
function doGet(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(360000)) {
    try {
      var okgo = e.parameter.okgo;
      allmatches();
    } catch (e) {
      lock.releaseLock();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput('Error!');
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput('Ok!');
    }
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Timeout!');
  }
}
```

I call this Web App by Python and in theory the answer should be `Error!`:

```python
import requests

okgo = 'go'
webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXX/exec"
url = webAppsUrl + "?okgo=" + okgo
web_app_response = requests.get(url)
print(web_app_response.text)
```

But the response is:

```
Ok!
```

What am I missing?

Add, when run without web app it goes into `catch`:

```
function test() {
    try {
      allmatches();
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ReferenceError: tl is not defined
```

Comment: `tl` is just `undefined`. It won't `throw`.

Comment: But @TheMaster when I run outside the Web App (I added an example at the end of the question), it goes as an exception in ```catch```, I couldn't understand the difference and how I can get around this, because when in Web App no error is reported by ```catch```

Comment: 1.What does your executions tab say? Any errors logged during webapp execution? 2.Try deploying it again and use the new url

Comment: WebApp ends without errors, there are no failure alerts in the logs.

Comment: Are you using the latest deployed url?

Comment: @TheMaster I'm actually using it on multiple different projects and just realized today, it's not a single web app issue. I tried to do what you said, but everyone keeps ignoring the errors and passing as ```Ok!```

Comment: Try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` at the end of `allmatches()`

Comment: I tried to add ```SpreadsheetApp.flush()``` and updated the Web App, but it keeps ignoring the error. Note: I've also tried to generate different errors to test, whatever they are, they pass as ```Ok!``` in the same way.

Comment: Try removing the `lock`.

Comment: @TheMaster I've tried now, with other types of errors too, but it keeps "ignoring" the errors.

Comment: `finally` is run regardless if there is an error or not.  Is it possible that the `ContentService.createTextOutput('Error!');` is quickly replaced by `ContentService.createTextOutput('Ok!');`?

Comment: That was exactly the problem @TheWizEd , I just did the test, so to adjust i remove ```finally``` and added ```ContentService.createTextOutput('Ok!')``` inside ```try```.

Comment: @TheWizEd Good catch. Consider adding it as a answer. This behavior is actually documented in the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) *Control flow will always enter the finally block, which can proceed Immediately before a control-flow statement (return, throw, break, continue) is executed in the try block or catch block.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by the following examples the `finally` block is run regardless if an error occurs or not.  So in the case of the OP `ContentService.createTextOutput('Error!');` is quickly replaced by `ContentService.createTextOutput('Ok!');` and the user is unaware of the error.

```
function testTry() {
  try {
    let x = a;
    console.log(x);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  finally {
    console.log("finally");
  }
}

7:52:56 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:52:58 AM  Info    [ReferenceError: a is not defined]
7:52:58 AM  Info    finally
7:52:57 AM  Notice  Execution completed

function testTry() {
  try {
    let x = 1;
    console.log(x);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  finally {
    console.log("finally");
  }
}

7:54:37 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:54:38 AM  Info    1
7:54:38 AM  Info    finally
7:54:38 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```